# How to convert HTML char to UNICODE char

Tags: c#, html, microsoft-metro

I need to convert HTML char eq. `&#8220;` to UNICODE char. I've tried to use function `HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText(string)` but unfortunately this function removes whatever exists between `<` and `>`. I need a sort of function that works as good as `WebView Control`, i.e HTML markups should be parsed or even removed while the others could be shown in a textblock. It should be used as converter for the textblock.

For example: nicks should be shown from the website bash.org

Comment: Do you actually mean **ASCII** or **UNICODE**? Note that ASCII cannot hold every extended code that Unicode can and therefore you will probably want to use Unicode to store the translation.

Comment: &#8220 is not an ASCII character. Do you mean you want to convert it to a printable character? That is, you want &#8220 to become `“`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I mean **UNICODE**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354.aspx). That should decode the values from the HTML entity (`&#8220;`) to a character.

Note that it's `WebUtility` since I think you're trying to accomplish this on a desktop application. If not, use `HttpUtility` instead.